# How do I get the best parts from a video?

Tags: editing

#### Status

I would like to do a gaming montage of my best moments (like [this](https://youtu.be/hkyOjDP3PPo?t=178) one).

Right now I have recordings with a total length of ~7h full of gameplay.

#### Problem

How can extract my best moments in a faster manner as watching the whole recordings without rewatching all my recordings?

Regardless if I speed up the recordings to x2 there are still >3,5 h to watch.

Answer (score 3):

Racingfail did a video on how they cut the best parts of racing from other contributers:

The general idea is the same as you have, but instead of seeing it at 2x, they do it at 16x.

Personally I use Davinci Resolve to skip though the video, with skipping 1 second ahead (shift+right), I see the stuff at ~30x. But any NLE has that functionality so go ahead!

If it's a recording you created, you might want to look at the waveform of the sound, if it's loud it's worth checking out (doesn't work if you have music going at the same time though)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion: create a catalog of images from the video with one image per 5 minutes - this is less than 100 images. Each image represents a timestamp. Review these images to remind yourself what scenes were interesting. Then review these scenes in the video manually and extract the interesting ones. I would do all of this using ffmpeg but I'm sure it can be done in many other ways.

- [Create a thumbnail image every X seconds of the video](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few tricks, but you won't get arpund it if you want to be exact.

Best way is to keep a record of funny moments. While you record - or edit the original videos - note down funny moments so you directly know where to go. You can use the Trick Christian Lindig wrote if you haven't done that to remember what you filmed and what was funny.

Another way would be to go through the audio and search loud parts, as they might be laughing.

You can also try to watch 4 videos at the same time. This needs some good consentration though.

If you really want THE BEST parts, you'll need to watch it.